# What is this equality called and what are the conditions?

Tags: probability, soft-question, conditional-probability

$P(A,B|C)=P(B|C)P(A|B,C)$

Does this property have a unique name? How do we derive it and what are the properties? Does it come from Bayes only or do we need other properties?

Comment: $$P(A,B|C)P(C)=P(A,B,C)$$
$$P(A|B,C)P(B|C)P(C)=P(A,B,C)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the definition of conditional probability.
Everything in the equation is "given $C$." So if we ignore that, it simplifies to
$$ P(A,B) = P(B)\cdot P(A|B)$$